# Android :How to load but not open URL

Tags: php, android, url

I have PHP link that updates totals on my database for my website. This website has no UI at all. When the user clicks on my button I just want it to load the link in the background and not view it. Using,

```
public void cButton(View view){
   Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

}
```

will prompt Android to open up its native browser, I just want to load the link.
Any methods you guys have in mind :) ?

Comment: clicking on that button will perform an operation?? is it a GET request?

Comment: I bet u need rest api to make http request! not clear what is ur purpose!!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you simply want to do an HTTP request? In this case you don't really want to start activity for loading the page in a browser. For such purpose Google is providing quite simple to use library. Hope this will help you: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Comment: Yes, just a HTTP request. Thank you :p